# Calculation help needed in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, jsfiddle

Why won't this short example work?  I am trying to get a total calculated on the fly, but it seems the function's aren't updating the total box.

In my actual work I am using radio buttons to update the pricing on the fly (rather than the button shown here), which each have an onclick function applied.

http://jsfiddle.net/jvEDt/1/

Any help would be amazing! Thanks very much

```
Your order total: <input type="text" id="totalbox" name="totalbox" size="10" maxlength="10" readonly="readonly" value="0.00" /><br>

<input name="Order" type="submit" value="Order" onclick ="JavaScript: calculateTotal();">

function calculateTotal()
{
var total = "5.00";
var totalbox = document.getElementById('totalbox');
totalbox.value = "£" + total;
}
```

Comment: You need to change the jsFiddle setting from `onLoad` to `No wrap - in <head>`. Then it will work.

Answer (score 1):

There are different settings in jsFiddle how the javascript should be treated.

**onLoad**
This executes the script when the body has loaded:

```
<body onLoad="<your script>">
```

**No wrap - in head**
This inserts the script in the `head` section:

```
<head>
  Your script
</head>
```

In your case you don't want to execute the script but rather include it on the page so that it's globally available. `No wrap - in head` is the setting you should use.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your function at run-time:

```
calculateTotal = function()
{
    // your code
}
```

Or you can change the place Javascript is loaded in the jsfiddle to `No wrap` as said in other answers.

Check this thread about run-time and parse-time defined functions: [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Answer (score 0):

additionaly:

```
<input name="Order" type="button" value="Order" onclick="calculateTotal();">
```

No spaces, no JavaScript: etc.